# ClassName to class_name

Tags: ruby, string, formatting, format, string-formatting

I'm sure this is an easy one for you geeks:

Say I have a String "ThisIsMyString" and I want to format it like "this_is_my_string" using Ruby.

How do I do that?

Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to ActiveSupport (as in Rails, but usable externally) you can use the `underscore` method in the [Inflector module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Inflector.html#M001631).

```
"ClassName".underscore # => class_name
```

Answer (score 2):

class String
   def to_under_score
      (gsub(/[A-Z]) { |p| "_" + p.downcase })[1..-1]
   end
end

"MyTestCase".to_under_score => "my_test_case"

From http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/113697#265696

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby Facets](http://facets.rubyforge.org/) has a function to do this: String#underscore.  Here's the [source](http://github.com/trans/facets/blob/85ca8a9d6c0aeb0a3357f96251ea3e4bc10b0339/lib/core/facets/string/underscore.rb) of it:

```
  def underscore
    gsub(/::/, '/').
    gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
    gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
    tr("-", "_").
    downcase
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to *ActiveSupport* from the *Rails* project, it's as simple as

```
require 'activesupport'
"ThisIsMyString".underscore
```

Comment: Just curious why my answer (who preceded the accepted answer by a minute or two and is essentially the same) got downvoted.

Comment: yeah, that seems a bit harsh. Maybe because you did the unnecessary (if you assume that it's a Rails project) require?